# GetUserNameW as wstring

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to know how to get the currenty logged on user's name as a wstring.

I only found LPWSTR examples like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    wchar_t name[UNLEN+1];
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;

    if (GetUserNameW( (LPWSTR)name, &size ))
    {
        cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Hello, unnamed person!\n";
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Can anybody tell me how to convert this to a wstring?

Thank you.

Comment: off topic-ish: [`std::wcout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the constructor for `std::wstring` on the value in `name` after calling `GetUserNameW`:

```
if(GetUserNameW(name, &len))
{
    std::wstring strname(name); 
    std::wcout << L"Hello, " << strname << std::endl;
}
```

If you're asking in general about why the Windows API doesn't support C++'s `std::` stuff out of the box, it's because it's designed to be compatibile with C first and foremost.